# Do Ubuntu VMs run smoothly on the MacBook Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015?

Tags: macbook-pro, unix, virtualbox

I need Ubuntu 14.04 for a class I'm doing, but I didn't want to install it side-by-side. Does VirtualBox run smoothly on the MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015)?

Comment: Can't speak about on a macbook, but on my iMac, running a Virtual Machine was the only way I could get my feet wet in Ubuntu.

Comment: I also have an iMac. Using the VM would be nice because maybe I could sync the machines between the two. Also, since there's no iCloud for linux, is there a way that I can connect my iCloud folder that's on my Mac to the VM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VirtualBox works very well with OS X as a host.

Performance will depend on the specs of your specific MacBook, but if you are responsible with your resources (don't have every one of your apps open at the same time), you probably won't have a problem.

Certainly won't hurt to try.

Comment: It's the entry MacBook([http://imgur.com/zGmsv0o](http://imgur.com/zGmsv0o)). The idea is that when using the VM I will only be using the VM.

Comment: A lot of variables (like what you're doing in the VM), but I think you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Also about others alternatives to VirtualBox(Parallels or VMware), do you think they perform better?

Comment: Not in my experience, definitely not Parallels.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I am gonna give VirtualBox a try. Hope it can do the task.

Comment: virtualbox is great for starting out for free. I'm using Parallels myself and contrary to @thedanielmatt I think it's the fastest available and my choice of VM software. Maybe just start out with Virtualbox and upgrade to a trial version of Parallels someday?

Comment: +1 for VirtualBox. I'm still using it to run occasional Win7 VMs on my 2006 MacBook. I get best performance when I quit other apps, but I've happily done some fairly hefty number crunching (re-encoding some binary data) from within the Win7 VM while tapping out some emails in Mail.app. I've even done a little gaming via VirtualBox on my old laptop (mainly GTA San Andreas and Battlefield 1942). Ubuntu should be lighter than Windows too. Having tried Parallels some years ago I couldn't see any perceivable performance gains above VirtualBox, things may have changed, but it's hard to beat free!

Comment: I think they all have niches and depends on what you're doing, but in my experience I default to VB (linux, DevOps, and Windows), then use Fusion (virtual OS X) if I need something else and have avoided Parallels (maybe it has gotten better).  Just my opinion...